# Does Cycles support udims for displacement?

Tags: materials, uv

As the title says: Is there currently a way to use udims/multi tile textures that go into cycles displacement output?

The only way i got it working is by creating a new material for every uv map. but this is not as handy as using a single material.

Comment: Nothing integrated as far as I know, but some links : http://www.pitiwazou.com/tips-deplier-les-uvs-en-udim-sur-blender/ or http://www.vertigostudio.es/blog/?p=94... all more or less simple to use...